# how can i get the same page with the click of back button of browser

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, updatepanel, back-button

i am using asp.net with c# in my aspx page i have an update panel in this panel i have some links to other sites, which is open on the same window. after clicking on these links me when i am getting back through browser's back button i am not getting the same results on the update panel...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have implement the same with the following Article, If you need further help, Plz let me know, I will provide chucks of code

http://rchern.wordpress.com/2008/05/11/updatepanel-backforward-browser-navigation/

First of all you have to Enable ScriptManager history EnableHistory="true"

  In this example we are maintaing gridview paging, When user browser back button
You have add history point after your page first time loads.

```
private void AddHistoryPoint(String key, String value, String tile)
{
    ScriptManager scm = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this.Page);
    if ((scm.IsInAsyncPostBack == true) && (scm.IsNavigating != true))
    {
        if (pageState == null)
        {
           NameValueCollection pageState = new NameValueCollection();
        }
        if (pageState[key] != null)
        {
            pageState[key] = value;
        }
        else
        {
            pageState.Add(key, value);
        }
        scm.AddHistoryPoint(pageState, tile);
    }
}

protected void grid_PageIndexChanged1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AddHistoryPoint("pi", grdProject.PageIndex.ToString(), "Page Index- " + (grdProject.PageIndex + 1).ToString());
}
```

here you have to handle ScriptManager Navigate Event

```
     protected void ScriptManager1_Navigate(object sender, System.Web.UI.HistoryEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.State != null)
    {
        if (e.State["pi"] != null)
        {
            grid.PageIndex = Convert.ToInt32(e.State["pi"]);
        }
    }
}
```