# Previous page should remain in same state when back button of browser is click

Tags: asp.net

I have a page on which there are two drop down lists, based on the selection of those dropdown lists grid view is filled. In grid view there are imagebuttons. When user clicks on any of the image button, he/she is redirected to another page. Now when I click on the back button of the browser, I want page in the same state as it was before redirect. How can I achieve this goal??

Comment: Is your gridview in updatepael?

Comment: @Muhammad Akhtar..Yes gridview and drop down lists all is in the same update panel...

Comment: get the code from this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/973739/how-can-i-get-the-same-page-with-the-click-of-back-button-of-browser/973753#973753

Answer (score 0):

use ASP.NET Multiview control instead of separate two pages this will create one page with two views which will effectively retain page state.
Please refer to these articles 
http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/MultiView-Control.aspx

[code project multiview](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/books/ASPNET20.aspx)