# GridView Sort Problem after Browser's Back Button Clicked

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a web form with a gridView inside an UpdatePanel.

After make a search and sort the gridview the user can click in a row to select the value to be edited, when it's clicked another page is opened.

The problem is, when the user click on the Browser's Back Button on EditPage the Search page doesn't keep the Sort and the Search previously set.

Any insight will be considered, please guys give me some way to get in!

Comment: Have a look at this article, I think it will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/973739/how-can-i-get-the-same-page-with-the-click-of-back-button-of-browser/973753#973753

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You, have to store the Searched result seperately in a DataView and should load into the Datagrid. Before going to the Edit Page Save the Sorting Term whether may be ASC or DESC in some Session Variable, and after clicking Back Button Resort with the Sorting Term.

Comment: Thanks for you support.
Yes I jsut tried it but without success, I detected that no one event is called when the user click on the back button. So I cannot re-fill those value to my gridView, I dont't know if you got my point..

Comment: But, in one of my project i also got the Same problem and i followed the same steps which i posted here as answer and it worked correctly. Can i post the Code also, so that you can refer it. But the Code is too long.