# How to maintain ajax results on Back

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a page in which I have 3 tabs. a 3-step wizard.
on the last step - I have an AJAX call to fetch data.
once clicked on each of the items in this data, I am redirecting the user to another page.

I want to maintain the wizard status (including ajax results) when the user presses BACK on the browser.

What is the best method to achieve this? using #step on the URL????

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at this thread answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/973739/how-can-i-get-the-same-page-with-the-click-of-back-button-of-browser/973753#973753

Comment: Thanks, but I use Jquery ajax, and not asp.net updatepanel

Answer (score 0):

Use the `history` object with a fallback on the hash.

[Manipulating the browser history](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history)

Comment: Didn't quite understood why do I need the history obj for that