# Browser back button doesn't work for Ajax Updatepanel click

Tags: ajax, updatepanel

I'm facing a crazy issue with in localhost *vs* production server.

Basically the issue is: browser back button doesn't have support for traversing in pagination, which works pretty fine in localhost. I am using Ajax update panel for pagination in grid view.

One more interesting stuff is: when I'm clicking on browser back button it appends a 404 URL, whereas I do not even have 404 page on my server.

the URL looks like:

```
http://www.example.com/404.aspx?404;http://www.example.com:80/domain-abcd/
```

I could able to travel all the pages in localhost and browser back button is properly responding taking me back to the previous page in gridview.

I am using IIS 6.0 and for rewrite URL Intelligencia UrlRewriter.

For this purpose I use the code below upon page load

```
form1.Action = Request.RawUrl
```

Any ideas on how to deal with, and fix these issues?

Comment: Two questions in one? I suggest splitting them into two separate posts.

Comment: I need  browser back button works for update panel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please view below links..

http://rchern.wordpress.com/2008/05/11/updatepanel-backforward-browser-navigation/

[how can i get the same page with the click of back button of browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/973739/how-can-i-get-the-same-page-with-the-click-of-back-button-of-browser/973753#973753)

Hope this will help you.